# Implementing a Carousel with Glass Mapper for Sitecore

Tags: glass-mapper

I am new to Sitecore hence, looking for help from Sitecore enthusiasts. 
I am implementing a carousel using Glass Mapper (V8.2)

I have a data source (a simple folder) which has three carousels as child items each of which consists an image, text and multiple links (tree list of navigation links)

This is the model for each carousel:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{B4AF4BE8-A1C4-42E3-A578-9B7B69066B3A}", AutoMap = true)]

public class Carousel
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual Image CarouselImage { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string CarouselText { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Links", Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.InferType)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<NavigationItem> CarouselLinks { get; set; }

}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{E7D13789-22BF-491D-9CF4-D8C2A2D16724}", AutoMap = true)]
public class NavigationItem
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.GeneralLink)]
    public virtual Link Url { get; set; }
}
```

This is how my view looks like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    @Html.Glass().RenderImage(item, x => x.CarouselImage, isEditable: true)
    <br />
    @foreach (var link in item.CarouselLinks)
    {
        @Html.Glass().Editable(link,x=>x.Title)
        @Html.Glass().RenderLink(link, x => x.Url, isEditable: true)
    }

    <br />
    @Html.Glass().Editable(item, x => x.CarouselText)


}
```

I am stuck on implementing the Controller where I could not get the child navigation item to be displayed. While debugging, I see it's only getting the links at level one and not the child links.

[image]
(For example here, the highlighted Tech Jobs is null)

```
var mvcContext = new MvcContext();

var currentItem = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;

IEnumerable<Carousel> carousels = currentItem.Children.Select(x => mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<Carousel>(x));

return View(carousels);
```

Your help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you published all your items? This can cause issues like this.

Comment: @Gravypower yes I did. In preview mode it should be getting from the master db though.

Comment: What data source item is selected in the presentation details?

Comment: @DanSinclair, The carousel folder which consists three carousel items is selected as the datasource in the presentation detail.

Comment: @DanSinclair, In the screenshot, for a carousel I have selected three navigation items. Two of them are Level 1 (Home and Employee) which is being displayed on the carousels. However the third one i.e. Tech Job (grand child of About Us) is not being displayed.